# C# String Split Between Dividers

Tags: c#, string, split

Maybe I misunderstood the title, sorry.
I have a string;

> This is a test string. It was opened on %Date% for the customer named
> %Customer%.

Here I want to be able to get a string containing "Date" and "Customer" with a method. How do I get the parts between the special characters "%" as strings?

Divider character and string can change dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract it with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.RexEx()`

`%[^%]*%"` - starts with `%`, ends with `%` but doesn't contain it `[^%]*`

```
string str = "This is a test string. It was opened on %Date% for the customer named %Customer%.";
string[] res = Regex.Matches(str, "%[^%]*%").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim('%')).ToArray();
```